# Installing Graylog2 with puppet

Tags: puppet, elasticsearch, graylog

I have manged to install Graylog2 from scratch by downloading all the DEB files and making the configurations. Now I try to install Graylog2 with the help of puppet in an environment and had no luck so far.

I am using [elasticsearch/elasticsearch](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch) and [graylog/graylog](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/graylog2/graylog2) from the forge.

This is my configuration so far:

```
#site.pp
node 'mynode' {
        class {'apt':
                proxy_host        =>  'proxynode',
                proxy_port        =>  '3142',
        }
        class {'toolbox':}
        class {'java':}
        class {'elasticsearch':
                ensure => 'present',
                #enabled => ensure running + enabled true
                status => 'enabled',

                ###only works with the repository
                #version => '1.3.2',
                package_url => 'puppet:///files/deb/elasticsearch-0.90.13.deb',
        }
        elasticsearch::instance {'graylog2':}
        class {'mongodb':}
        class {'graylog2::repo':
                version => '0.21',
        } ->
        class {'graylog2::server':
                service_enable => 'true',
                rest_listen_uri => "http://${::ipaddress}:12900",
                rest_transport_uri => "http://${::ipaddress}:12900",
                #verysecurepw
                password_secret         => 'cdebc192e0ae1f5df753018a8d284b9eacf2042d55fb712f7a89260c3fc3668d',
                root_password_sha2      => 'cdebc192e0ae1f5df753018a8d284b9eacf2042d55fb712f7a89260c3fc3668d',
        } ->
        class {'graylog2::web':
                application_secret      => 'cdebc192e0ae1f5df753018a8d284b9eacf2042d55fb712f7a89260c3fc3668d',
                graylog2_server_uris            => ["http://${::ipaddress}:12900"],
        }

}
```

The deb packages are downloaded successfully and installed as well.
When I use a custom elasticsearch instance it starts up automatically, if I don't the instance does not start.

However if I try to start graylog-server it gives me the following:

```
ERROR: Could not successfully connect to ElasticSearch. Check that your cluster state is not RED and that ElasticSearch is running properly.
```

Checking the Elasticsearch service:

```
curl -XGET 'http://192.168.0.1:9200/_cluster/health?pretty=true'
{
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "status" : "green",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 2,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 2,
  "active_primary_shards" : 0,
  "active_shards" : 0,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 0
}
```

Looks OK

Looking on the Webpage 192.168.0.1:9000 gives me an error that graylog-web service can't connect to the server.

Maybe I am missing a connection between graylog and Elasticsearch, but I can't seem to find it.

The Graylog Error Log:

```
2014-09-09T12:02:54.383+02:00 ERROR [ServiceManager] Service IndexerSetupService [FAILED] has failed in the STARTING state.
java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at org.graylog2.UI.exitHardWithWall(UI.java:40)
        at org.graylog2.indexer.Indexer.start(Indexer.java:205)
        at org.graylog2.initializers.IndexerSetupService.startUp(IndexerSetupService.java:66)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractIdleService$2$1.run(AbstractIdleService.java:54)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Callables$3.run(Callables.java:95)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2014-09-09T12:02:54.394+02:00 ERROR [InputSetupService] Not starting any inputs because lifecycle is: Uninitialized?[LB:DEAD]
2014-09-09T12:02:54.404+02:00 INFO  [PeriodicalsService] Shutting down periodical [org.graylog2.periodical.DeflectorManagerThread].
2014-09-09T12:02:54.404+02:00 INFO  [PeriodicalsService] Shutdown of periodical [org.graylog2.periodical.DeflectorManagerThread] complete, took <0ms>.
```

---snip---

Comment: Could you add the URL to the puppet code? Did you check the Graylog-server log?

Comment: I did check the Graylog-server-log. I added it at the end.
I am not sure what do you mean by the URL of the puppetcode? There forge repositories are now linked to the forge if you mean that.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use elastic search version elasticsearch-0.90.10 they say it is compatible with elasticsearch-1.3.2 in the changelog but I had the same error as you using the newer elasticsearch